# Linq query without column names

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to write a LINQ query by using Select OR Where Clause on the retrieved list. However, the list does not have a column name, only values are there.
So my question is how can I get the values based on this condition?

For e.g. the list contains Approved, OnHold status. However, I Want to get the records for 'Approved' status only from the list.
Below is my code

```
SpreadsheetsResource.ValuesResource.GetRequest request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, range);

ValueRange response = request.Execute();
IList<IList<object>> values = response.Values;
```

And below is the screenshot how the values look in the list

[image]

The list with the name 'values' contains all of the records.

Any help on this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is coming back as an Collection, so you can either access the properties via their numerical index, e.g.

`var approvedResults = values.Where(c => c[7] == "Approved");`

Or you can map it to a proper object, something like

```
public class MyResultObject {
   public DateTime date {get; set;}
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   ...
   public string ApprovedStatus {get; set;}

   public MyResultObject(string[] values)
   {
       date = DateTime.Parse(values[0]);
       FirstName = (string) values[1];
       ...
       etc.
   }
}
```

Then use linq to convert your data into a bunch of those, which will be much nicer.

```
var myResultObjects = values.Select(c => new MyResultObject(c.Select(x => (string)x).ToArray());
```

You might have to tweak some of the code because I don't know exactly how `ValueRange` works and I'm just typing this out without checking it, but that's the gist.

Then you can do `myResultObjects.Where(c => c.ApprovedStatus == "Approved");` which is much nicer.

Comment: By using var approvedResults = values.Where(c => c[7] == "Approved");

 it is giving error as Index out of range exception

Comment: My guess is that some of your records don't have all 8 columns of data coming back. You should check the data quality. In fact you can see in your screenshot, it says `Count = 9` for some and `Count = 8` for another. If you have a record where the count is less than 8 then it will cause this error because there isn't a column at [7] to read.

Comment: Yeah.. Just found that while debugging.. But I dont have any control on data which is coming.. So how can we check this ?

Comment: If the data doesn't have a column for `Approved` then how will you check if it is approved or not?

Comment: The problem is, there is one line which only has date field after that its starts again. That line causing the issue

Comment: You could filter, simply do `values.Where(c => c.Length > 7 && c[7] == "Approved");`. Probably nicer to have another step beforehand that sanitises the data though, perhaps removing invalid entries.

Answer (score -2):

I have achieved this by using below line of code

```
var result = values.Where(x => x.Contains("Approved")).ToList();
```

This is going to give me only records with 'Approved' status.

Thanks !

Comment: In that case, isn't `x` your array? So it's searching every value... If you had a person with a surname `Approved` then it would match even if the status wasn't approved. So it won't give you records with Approved status, it will give you anything that has any column containing the word 'Approved'... Plus it's not very efficient to check every column.

Comment: @NibblyPig Yes Agree with this ! Will change as per your answer